# Cachem corrupt in R

Tags: r

I am using R in a platform similar to Colab, and I first library some packages

```
install.packages("pacman")
library(pacman)
p_load(readxl)
p_load(dplyr)
p_load(tidyr)
p_load(statnet)
```

and I read in my data, everything is fine until now.

And then I install ergm.tapered from github and run ergm.tapered model.
Then it says:

> Warning message in is_old_cache(cache): “restarting interrupted
> promise evaluation” Warning message in is_old_cache(cache): “internal
> error -3 in R_decompress1” Error in is_old_cache(cache): lazy-load
> database '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/cachem/R/cachem.rdb' is corrupt

sometimes it says

> Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘cachem’ is imported by
> ‘memoise’ so cannot be unloaded

So I think it is cachem problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Also, when I ran my code on my laptop, everything is fine...